# Install Mercury after XAMPP installation

Tags: installation, xampp, mercury-mta

I have initially installed XAMPP without checking the Mercury installation.
Of course, the module shows-up in the XAMPP Control panel but is disabled and there is no mean to install it from there. How should I do without re-installing the whole XAMPP package?

Comment: I would just like to add that creating the \xampp\mercury\ folder and pointing the installation there did not work for me as xampp was actually looking for mercury in \xampp\MercuryMail instead.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For who would be interested (that applies to any not-initially-installed module of XAMPP package):

1. create a folder inside xampp, e.g. \xampp\mercury. In windows it should be "MercuryMail".
2. download mercury from here: http://www.pmail.com/downloads_s3_t.htm
3. during installation, point to the \xampp\mercury\ folder.
4. edit the file \xampp\xampp-control.ini:

   [EnableModules]->Mercury=1

   [BinaryNames]->Mercury=mercury.exe

Reload XAMPP Control panel
That's all!

Comment: I tried this. The program should be installed to MercuryMail, not Mercury for Xampp to detect it properly.

Comment: Renaming the directory won't help, you have to uninstall it again if you already installed it to Mercury directory. This method worked for me and I now have a green light in Xampp.

Comment: doesnt work for me.  All is disabled in grey colour for Mercury in xampp control panel